# how to write to a cell from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

seems like a dumb question even for a VBA newbie, but I can't figure out how to write to a cell in VBA...  I have a function in "Module1" that looks like this:

```
Function Foo(bar As Boolean)
  Range("A1").Value = 1
  Foo = ...
End Function
```

Then say I set Cell A2's formula to:

```
=Foo(true)
```

The call itself works if I take out the range setting line... in that case setting the calling cell to the foo value.  But I'd like this to eventually write a ton of cells at once rather than have a different function call for each cell.  What am I doing wrong???

---

If this code should work as is... are there settings in Excel 2007 that might be blocking editing a cell, or something like that?

Comment: it's not exactly clear what you intend this function to do..

Comment: It seems odd that you are ignoring the errors parameter in your function. Is this your full code?

Comment: its not important, all I'm trying to get to work is writing out cells from a VBA function that reacts to inputs from a range of other cells... I'll take out everything that doesn't matter for clarity

Comment: +1, tho I wish the title was more descriptive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.contextures.com/xlfaqmac.html), it's not possible for an Excel user defined function to alter other parts of the Workbook.  Looks like you may have to try another way.

Comment: that is disappointing... my vba will be calling a foreign dll that requires a large number of input cells, and returns a large number of outputs to be displayed in a range of output cells.  I need to avoid calling the dll for each cell... while still causing the dll to be called whenever an input changes.

Comment: You could use the Worksheet_Change event in that case. This event is raised every time a cell on your page changes.  This event can be used to change other cells.

Comment: if I write out cells to the same worksheet using a Worksheet_Change event, would I get circular references?  Or could I test individual cells for changes?

Comment: Surround your code with Application.EnableEvents = False and Application.EnableEvents = True which will stop the code from firing again.  You can also test individual cells if you wish inside your code using Intersect.

Comment: so it looks like there would be problems both with circular references and updates only happening when a user changed a value on the current sheet, rather than updates being driven from other sheets.

Comment: If the input coming from other sheets is also provided by that sheet's Worksheet_Change event, then yes, that could be a problem if you disable the application's events. I'm sure there will be ways to work around it though!

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom function in VBA enter the following in a Module

```
Public Function MyCalc(ByRef r as Range) as Double
    MyCalc = r.Value^2
End Function
```

or

```
Public Function MyCalc(ByVal x as Double) as Double
    MyCalc = x^2
End Function
```

and use it on a worksheet as `=MyCalc(A2)` which returns and sets the appropriate value. Choose if you want to pass a value, or a range depending on what you want to do.